# Select multiple rows using multiple data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hiding rows for given `id`s using this code:

```
var idArray = ['A123','B456']; // getting from web services
for (var i=0;i<idArray.length;i++) {
   var id = idArray[i];
   $("#eTable tr[data-empid=" + id + "]").hide();
}
```

**HTML (Just for example doesn't needs improvement)**

```
<table id="eTable">
    <tr data-empid="A123" data-salary="120" data-status="drone">
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Vogel</td>
        <td>Principal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-empid="B456" data-salary="130" data-status="worker">
        <td>Jan</td>
        <td>Vogel</td>
        <td>General Manager</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-empid="C789" data-salary="110" data-status="worker">
        <td>Jason</td>
        <td>van de Velde</td>
        <td>Company nurse</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can we improve this code as it is selecting same table again and again to get row one by one instead of getting them once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend caching your `<table>` selector before the loop and simplifying the loop.

```
var idArray = ['A123','B456']; // getting from web services
var len = idArray.length;  // get the length
var $tbl = $('#eTable');  //cache the table selector

while (len--) {
 $tbl.find("tr[data-empid=" + idArray[len] + "]").hide();
}
```

This way you aren't re-selecting the entire table from the DOM on each loop.
Also, since it doesn't matter what order the rows are hidden, the `while(len--)` is typically the "fastest" way to do a loop.  No extra lookup to find the value of `i` and no recalculating of `idArray.length` on each loop.

In vanilla JavaScript:

```
var idArray = ['A123','B456']; // getting from web services
var len = idArray.length;  // get the length
var tbl = document.getElementById('eTable');  //cache the table selector

while (len--) {
 tbl.querySelector("tr[data-empid=" + idArray[len] + "]").style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: @Thriggle Crap!  I didn't see that.  Thanks for the catch!  Updated.

Answer (score 3):

The performance benefits vary depending on the browser's implementation of ECMAScript, but you can usually get a modest performance improvement by selecting the parent element first, then selecting only child elements of that parent element. [This jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/id-and-css-selectors/2) somewhat demonstrates the difference.

In native JavaScript, this is done by selecting the parent element with `document.querySelector`, `document.getElementById`, or `document.getElementsByTagName`. You can then call a similar selector method on that element instead of on `document` to limit your search to only child elements.

**Native**

```
var idArray = ['A123','B456']; 
var table = document.querySelector("#eTable");
for(var i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++){
    table.querySelector("tr[data-empid='"+idArray[i]+"']").style.display = "none";
}
```

In jQuery, you can achieve the same using `jQuery(parentElement).find(selector)` or `$(parentElement).find(selector)`

**jQuery**

```
var idArray = ['A123','B456']; 
var table = $("#eTable");
for(var i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++){
   $(table).find("tr[data-empid='"+idArray[i]+"']").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already a couple good answers to this, but I thought I'd take a different tack and use selectors rather than loops. Since you have an array of ids, you can use the fact that `querySelectorAll` and `find` can take multiple, comma-separated selectors within a single string and build one using `join`. So now, no more loops (except the implicit one in `map`).

```js
var idArray = ['A123','B456']; // getting from web services

// Create selector
var selectors = idArray.map(function (id) { return 'tr[data-empid="' + id + '"]'; });
var selector = selectors.join(', ');

// Use plain JavaScript
var els = document.querySelector('#eTable').querySelectorAll(selector);
Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function (el) { el.style.display = 'none'; });

// Use jQuery
$('#eTable').find(selector).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="eTable">
    <tr data-empid="A123" data-salary="120" data-status="drone">
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Vogel</td>
        <td>Principal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-empid="B456" data-salary="130" data-status="worker">
        <td>Jan</td>
        <td>Vogel</td>
        <td>General Manager</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-empid="C789" data-salary="110" data-status="worker">
        <td>Jason</td>
        <td>van de Velde</td>
        <td>Company nurse</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```